# New Activity OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to start a new `Activity` after change a piece of a view `OnNavigationItemSelected`.
I'm able to change the view correctly:

```
 if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        setTitle(fragment.getArguments().getString("title"));
        drawer.setSelected(true);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
}
```

With this, I want to change a piece of my main view where I want to show something depending on the chosen option.

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="es.antonio.miBoda.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_gallery** (I update the main view with this view)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/label"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Edit fragment_connect.xml to change the appearance"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ic_take_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can update the view perfectly but, when I start the new activity, I'm not able to get the floating button `ic_take_picture`, it's always `null`.

My **GalleryActivity**

```
public class GalleryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton takePicture = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_take_picture);
        if (null != takePicture) {
            takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The only way how I can get the button is doing `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_gallery);` but If I do that, my view change and is not like the main view.

So, how I can start the new Activity after do the view replacement to have available the floating button?

Comment: pass the position of selection based on that replacing the view using setcontentview()

Comment: where? I don't understand you.

Comment: "" With this, I want to change a piece of my main view where I want to show something depending on the chosen option.""  this s what you write in the question or i cant get you?

Comment: I think that you don't undertand the question. I don't want to replace the whole view, only a piece of it, so I can't use setContentView. What I want is that have availables new items in my current view, that's why I'm using the replace.

Comment: i think you looking for fragment workflow you can change multiple fragments in single activity. If you go to new activity completey you cannot refer items in previous activity.

Comment: Instead of activity create new fragment and replace fragment. have a look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I need to start a new activity because now I want to show a gallery, so it have no sense to do all in the MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I have added this to my fragment instead of create a new Activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FloatingActionButton takePicture = (FloatingActionButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.ic_take_picture);
    if (null != takePicture) {
        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Reading [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) it's all much clear.